# POST parameters in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, express

I am working on a simple texteditor that saves and loads text files through an Node/ExpressJS server. Loading is fine, but saving doesn't work yet due to me not being able to transmit the data to the server-app correctly.

[image]

I send the data via XMLHttpRequest to the server in a POST request, which works fine according to the network-profiler in dev-tools, the 'handler_save' function is called, but no parameters are received.

**What am I doing wrong?** *(here is a snippet of the server code, altered for demonstration:)*

```
express = require('express')();

function init_save_load(){
  var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  express.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  express.use('/save', handler_save );
  express.use('/load', handler_load );
}

...

function handler_save(req, res){
  console.log(req.body);    // "{name:post.txt,data:testing}"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure you are parsing the request body so it can work

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser());
```

bodyParser is a part of "Connect", a set of middlewares for node.js. Here's the real docs and source from Connect: http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/bodyParser.html

finally console log the req.body and see what is in there

```
 console.log(req.body)
```

Comment: I modified the init_load_save function with the body parser. It is still not working though.

Comment: you are not calling init_load_save?

Comment: I am. Otherwise the handler_save function would not be called upon making a request with my browser.

Comment: console.log body what does it give now console.log(req.query); ?

Comment: I tried console.log(req.body), which finally gives me the parameters. *happy*

Comment: okay let me edit the answer so it helps and save time of others too, great(Y)

Answer (score 1):

Not only do you need to use a body parsing middleware as Abdul mentioned, but your request needs to have the correct `Content-Type`. Currently you are sending `Content-Type: text/plain`, but it should be `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for simple forms or `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` for forms containing files.

Comment: Thanks, I heard some people mention this before, though I didn't know it was that important. Sadly I am still not getting it to work.